# Using other's class methods in my payload with Mule

Tags: java, xml, mule, mule-studio

I created a Mule app that takes data from some json feeds and transforms them with a custom transformer I made to create a class.

I have a parent class `Event` and two subclasses that inherit from it: `Event1` and `Event2`. The return class of my custom transformer (`auto-transformer`) is `Event`.

I am using a choice flow control component so when a certain data value is reached for the `Event1` a mail is sent, and when a certain data value is reached for `Event2` a different mail is sent.

In `Event1` I defined the method `getThisData()` and in `Event2` I defined `getThatData()`.

When I use `#[payload.getThisData()]` everything works, the value is checked, and the mail is sent if the condition is true.

However, for the `Event2` branch it doesn't work. It gives me an error. It tries to look for the `getThatData()` in the `Event1` class, and obviously it does not exist.

How can I fix this? How can I get the value from `getThatData()`?

I use Mule Studio.

```
<processor-chain>
    <auto-transformer returnClass="events.Event" name="JSONToEvent"></auto-transformer>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[payload.getThisData()&gt;1200]">
            <twitter:update-status config-ref="Twitter" status="Value reached"/>
        </when>
        <when expression="#[payload.getThatData()&gt;11]">
            <twitter:update-status config-ref="Twitter" status="The other value reached"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <twitter:update-status config-ref="Twitter" status="#[payload]" doc:name="Normal"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</processor-chain>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the payload class in the expression:

```
#[payload instanceof events.Event2 &amp;&amp; payload.getThatData()&gt;11]
```

Comment: Now it says org.mule.api.routing.RoutePathNotFoundException: Can't process message because no route has been found matching any filter and no default route is defined. Failed to route event via endpoint: ChoiceRouter [flow-construct=flow1, started=true]. Message payload is of type: Event1

Comment: This error means you have no `otherwise` branch. Did you remove it, or do you have a typo somewhere?